# Stack Board Output

Tags: java, stack, output

How would I fix the output?

```
int row = 4, cols = 4;
Stack<Piece> board[][] = new Stack[row]
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                board[i][j] = new Stack<Piece>();               
                System.out.println(board[i][j]);

            }
        }
```

this is what I get:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

I am trying to get to right output as this:

```
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```

4x4 board, instead of every line.

It would be great if you guys can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`println` always adds the newline. Use `print` in the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        board[i][j] = new Stack<Piece>();               
        System.out.print(board[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Allow me 7 minutes before I can accept you as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `System.out.println(board[i][j]);` to `System.out.print(board[i][j]);` and insert `System.out.println();` after the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you! Just like trogdor. I wish I can mark both answer at once.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println prints a new line character at the end of your string.

Use System.out.print(board[i][j]) and then after your column loop but within your row loop do a System.out.println("") to print a new line character.